# Getting ugcPost details through rest/posts api?

Tags: linkedin-api

I could not get the ugcPost of a post or comment, the urn looks like: urn:li:ugcPost:7023566176156811264,7023567581345140736

how to use this in the api rest/posts/{ugcPosts urn}

the API returns the error {
"message": "Could not find entity",
"status": 404,
"code": "NOT_FOUND"
}

I have also added the headers
{
Linkedin-Version: 202210,
X-RestLi-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0
}
but it is still returning the same error even though I have encoded the urn, example:
https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts/urn%3Ali%3AugcPost%3A7023566176156811264?viewContext=Reader

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a bearer token in the header. And viewContext=Reader params is not required as per my knowledge of the documentation. I am sharing a sample example.

```
  var axios = require('axios');
    var config = {
      method: 'get',
      url: 'https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts/urn%3Ali%3AugcPost%3A7023566176156811264',
      headers: { 
        'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0', 
        'LinkedIn-Version': '202208', 
        'Authorization': 'Bearer [your_bearer_token]', 
      }
    };
    
    axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

You can visit this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/posts-api?view=li-lms-2023-01&tabs=http#get-posts-by-urn) for more information.